# Can't use PowerMockRule with spring

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, powermock

i want to use PowerMockRule with spring, and my test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ WebContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {
        SpringConfig.class, SpringTestingConfig.class,
        SpringLocalContainerJPAConfig.class, CustomConfiguration.class })
@PrepareForTest({ FacesContext.class })
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "javax.xml.parsers.*",
        "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.*", "ch.qos.logback.*",
        "org.slf4j.*" })
public class MyTestClass{

@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

}
```

and my jars are as follows:

```
<powermock.version>1.5.1</powermock.version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope> 
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
          <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
          <version>${powermock.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
          <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
          <version>${powermock.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
         <version>${powermock.version}</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

but when running the test i am getting the following exception:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Could not call org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference.readResolve() : Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@34e5190a: no factory registered for this id : Could not call org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference.readResolve() : Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@34e5190a: no factory registered for this id
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Could not call org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference.readResolve() : Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@34e5190a: no factory registered for this id
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException
cause-message       : Could not call org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference.readResolve() : Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@34e5190a: no factory registered for this id
class               : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference
required-type       : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1/outer-class/fNext/next/next/fNext/fTarget/userService/handler/advised/org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport/default/advisorArray/org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor[3]/advice/persistenceExceptionTranslator/delegates/org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean/beanFactory
line number         : 52
class[1]            : org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$SerializedEntityManagerFactoryBeanReference
class[2]            : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
class[3]            : org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator
class[4]            : org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
class[5]            : org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor
class[6]            : [Lorg.springframework.aop.Advisor;
converter-type[2]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.ArrayConverter
class[7]            : org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory
converter-type[3]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter
class[8]            : org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy
class[9]            : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper$DynamicProxy
converter-type[4]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DynamicProxyConverter
class[10]           : test.myapp.web.controllers.SignUpBeanTest
class[11]           : org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod
class[12]           : org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores
class[13]           : org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks
class[14]           : org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks
class[15]           : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement
class[16]           : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1
version             : null
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:61)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.ArrayConverter.unmarshal(ArrayConverter.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter$2.defaultReadObject(SerializableConverter.java:370)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter.doUnmarshal(SerializableConverter.java:415)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DynamicProxyConverter.unmarshal(DynamicProxyConverter.java:118)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1052)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1036)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:912)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:903)
    at org.powermock.classloading.DeepCloner.clone(DeepCloner.java:54)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:89)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException: Could not call org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference.readResolve() : Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@34e5190a: no factory registered for this id
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializationMethodInvoker.callReadResolve(SerializationMethodInvoker.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:235)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@34e5190a: no factory registered for this id
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference.readResolve(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1043)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializationMethodInvoker.callReadResolve(SerializationMethodInvoker.java:65)
    ... 132 more
```

please advise how to fix that, thanks.

Comment: What is the situation, if you run the test without PowerMockRule?

Comment: @Christopher Roscoe, it works fine without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post solved my problem :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/powermock/bmH8osYhsbQ/gT4-J32T5QkJ

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your test is using PowerMock's classloader instead of the Spring one:

...
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:89)

Have you tried running PowerMock as an agent? I.e. adding the VM param:

-javaagent:c:\blabla\.m2\repository\org\powermock\powermock-module-javaagent\1.5.4\powermock-module-javaagent-1.5.4.jar